# Certain apps start up slowly, some start fine and some do not start at all after login in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, firefox, startup, brave

when I turn on my computer and login, my desktop is fully loaded but when I open certain apps (Brave) it shows Brave starting at the top but everything just stays that way for a few seconds and then nothing happens.

Strangely, when I try to open certain other applications (Firefox) the application opens immediately.

Even more strangely, there is a third category of applications that when opened after login it takes 30 seconds or so but it does open. (VS Code)

Are these issues caused by the same problem that I can fix?

Comment: Hello. Sounds like perfectly natural performance. You have not given any info on your hardware. The larger the app the longer it takes to load and run. BTW the title and the question do not match. Nothing in the question about installation. Please correct.

Comment: How did you install Brave or VS Code? Are they snap apps?

Comment: Sounds like Brave is a snap and Firefox is not …

Comment: During startup, Ubuntu does many tasks, checks for updates, gnome issues etc. Use a process manager to see which apps are using much of your CPU. Like David said, it's a perfectly natural thing to expect.

Comment: @David right, the question changed as I thought of more details.  The question is fixed now, thanks for pointing that out.  It is 'normal behavior' for some apps not to open at all directly after login?  If i login and then wait a few minutes the problem changes from apps like Brave going from category 1 where it does not open at all to category 2 where the app opens but takes 30 seconds.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I think one app is installed via snap and the other is not... is there a way I can check?

Comment: @matigo I think that is the case, how do I know which is the good installation method that causes no problems and which method is causing the issues? I want to install all apps the non-problematic way.

Comment: @GiorgosSaridakis do you have a recommended process manager or should I just find any one?

Comment: I always use htop. sudo apt install htop . Small and powerful, runs from the terminal.

Comment: @GiorgosSaridakis upon installation, do I open it immediately after login or is there a log I read?

Comment: Usually snap apps are slower on cold start. You can install the .deb versions of these apps, and check if there is any improvement.

Comment: open it the moment you want it, open up a terminal and type htop . if you want it to start-up automatically, add it to startup applications from your menu.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `snap list`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.